# Determine the value of x for which matrix F has only real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $F =$ $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\x & 3\end{bmatrix}$, *how* would one determine values of $x$ for which $F$ only has real eigenvalues?

Comment: Do you know how to determine the eigenvalues of $F$?

Comment: Using the characteristic polynomial of $F$, but I am struggling with interpreting that equation with respect to $x$ to answer the question.

Comment: What did you get for the characteristic polynomial of $F$?

Comment: @Tanner thanks so much, I appreciate the help! Both you and vujazzman helped me out here. I realize that the problem is solved by taking the characteristic polynomial and solving $b^2-4ac \ge0$ in terms of $x$. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial, and solve for the condition that it is nonnegative